# show shared folders in dialog box in elevated privilege software

Tags: c#

I have developed an application with CEFSHARP where a web page is loaded, it happens that I am trying to upload PDF files but I cannot get the dialog box to show the shared folders:

manifest file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
        <applicationRequestMinimum>
            <PermissionSet Unrestricted="true" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
            <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
        </applicationRequestMinimum>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

i know that it is related with:

```xml
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

the only solution i find in internet is this:

1. run regedit
2. locate `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System`
3. create a new DWORD entry with the name `EnableLinkedConnections` and value 1.
4. restart your computer
5. now you can see and use network drives with these installers or applications.

But I can't tell all users that they need to change something in their S.O with regedit.

Is there any way to allow showing network location to application running by admin user / privileges?

Comment: You need elevated privilege to write to HKLM.  What I would do is create a separate program, manifest it to `"requireAdministrator"`, and in that program, do the registry edit.  Only admins will be able to do that.  The trick it to have it separate from your regular app.

Comment: the problem is that visual studio not show the vc++ 2015 insteas of it show a "14" RTL, version is the same, this is ambiguous it should improve ... cefsharp does not say anything about "14" RTL version?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment.  Where does "VC++ 2015" figure into this (your question is tagged with `C#`).  What is _"14" RTL_ and how does that figure into your question.  The first time "14" (or RTL) shows is in your comment.  What is RTL (the first thing that popped into my head was the bus company in some Montreal suburbs).

Answer (score 0):

You could make the registry edit using C# instead of regedit

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

public class Example
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    const string keyName = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System";
    Registry.SetValue(keyName, "EnableLinkedConnections", 1);      
  }
}
```